# include(Mage.php) causes wrong URL when executed from command line

Tags: magento-1.7

I need to run some Magento code from PHP file in nearby directory. So I created a file, lets call it `test.php`:

```
include_once '/var/www/html/app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app();

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', 'some-sku-123');

echo $product->getProductUrl();
```

When I open it from browser correct product URL is printed - `http://example.com/product123.html`.

But when I execute this PHP file from command line via `php path/to/test.php`, such URL is printed: `test.php/product123.html`.

What's even more strange, is that previously it was working correctly, and I can't find what change did I make.

So my question is how to make sure that correct URL is printed when executed from command line?

Thank you.

edit: `Mage::getBaseUrl()` also returns incorrect value - `test.php/`.

Answer (score 4):

Magento doesn't know in which context you are, therefore I would assume no `base_url` is set.

Try to set a context with:

```
Mage::app($code = '', $type = 'store')
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, but it doesn't help. The same URL is printed (test.php/). Here is the exact code that I'm using https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9921b161b1354f8ae858

Comment: Ok, so I just ran command `service httpd restart` to restart apache, and ran `php test.php` again and it worked correctly (even with `Mage::app();`). Very weird.

Comment: ... and 3 minutes later it stopped working again :/ https://gist.github.com/anonymous/151f8d72e6f1ec737a64

Comment: this is weird. No idea. Time to use xdebug and check what is happening. Does magento find the right store, loads the right config...

Comment: I gave up and just decided to use `wget` instead of CLI `php` to execute php file.